# Animate Flutter DataTable

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm relatively new to Flutter and am now trying to animate some of my widgets.

I'm currently struggling to animate my DataTable. I have a dynamically built DataTable that has to be able to add and delete values. I'm trying to animate insertions and deletions of a new Column. Right now this is happening instantaneously.

[image: demo]

I've seen that Flutter offers a lot of animated widgets out of the box already. For example [AnimatedList](http://AnimatedList) which would probably be perfect. Unfortunately, I haven't found any alternatives like that for the DataTable widget.

How would one go on to animate something like this?